# On click, change opacity and fade in hidden div

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

I was wondering what would be the most efficient way to perform this. I have tried many methods that were posted on here but had no results.

I currently have a table row, that when it is clicked, I want it to change the opacity of the row and fade in two buttons.

```
<tr id="row1">
<td>Text</td>
<td>Text</td>
<td><div id="hidden">Text</div></td>
```

I'm using tables for data reasons. Essentially I'm wondering how to make it so when you click #row1, it fades the opacity and fades in the id #hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4utt9/

One way to do this is use `animte` and `fadeIn`. It isn't clear if you want the previously hidden buttons to have the same new opacity as the row when they appear. But you can change this in the CSS.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr').on('click', function(event) {
        var $row = $(this);
        $row.animate({ opacity: 0.5}, function() {
            $row.find('.hidden').fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

If you want the hidden part to not be partially transparent, you can do this:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4utt9/6/

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr id="row1">
        <td>Text 1</td>
        <td>Text 2</td>
        <td class="hidden">
            <div>Text Hidden</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr').on('click', function(event) {
        var $row = $(this);
        $row.find('td:not(.hidden)').animate({ opacity: 0.5}, function() {
            $row.find('.hidden').fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What if I want text in the 3rd div. 
    <td>Text</td> This lowers in opacity 
    <div>This is hidden</div> This shows up when the above is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

See fadeTo: http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

```
$('#row1').click(function()
{
  $(this).fadeTo(500, 1); // 100% opacity.  change 1 to .9 or whatever other value between 0 and 1 you want
  $(this).find('#hidden').fadeIn(); // fade all the way in.  Could just do $('#hidden') but I assume your code will evolve to where it will be a div with a class of hidden instead of an ID, as an ID must be unique per HTML document
});
```

Bonus points, add a class to your rows, or a class to your table so you can target that instead of `row1` by ID, e.g.

```
<table class="my-table">
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
</table>
```

then

```
$('.my-table tr').click(function() { ... });
```

Comment: Thanks for the first part, that makes sense to me. I had similar code to that which makes the row lower the opacity but also show the #hidden div and then fade that to the same opacity. Is there a way not to fade the #hidden, it seems to be hidden because it's a child of the TR.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  You want to show hidden but not fade it?  Just pop it in w/out fading?

Answer (score 0):

Other answers aren't taking into account that changing the opacity of the tr affects the opacity of its children

```
$('#row1').on('click', function(){
    $(this).find('td').animate({opacity:0.5}, 1000);
    $(this).find('#hidden').fadeIn().parent().stop().css({opacity:1});
});
```